# Grid validation not always working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a grid with data bound on it. When a certain field contains an invalid time (00:00:00), the validation fails and the grid should show a red border.

This works fine and when validating the individual field, the validation works perfectly. In the grid however, sometimes it does not display the red border, even though the value is exactly the same and the validation fails:

[image]

As you see, the middle rowd isplays the red border, while the others don't. The 2 values are exactly the same in the database.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Note: it has nothing to do with the different colors on the different rows. This seems to happen at random rows.

Grid:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Rides, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" Height="350" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"  CanUserSortColumns="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRide}" Margin="0,0,0.4,0" >
        <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
            <DataErrorValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="False" />
        </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            //columns

            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            //button
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Some detail would be nice, you've only given us an outline.

Comment: What kind of details would you like to see? XAML code?

Comment: The code you use to determine if the border should be red, the code you use to set the red border, the event it resides within, and yes the definition of the xaml grid might prove usefull...

Comment: There's no specific code to determine if the border should be red... I assume the default is used. I've added the XAML code, thanks

Comment: I suppose that the validation is just not called in some cases.
You can check this by setting a breakpoint in your ValidationRule.
If this is the case it may have to do with your datasource: i.e. in order to support DataBinding you would need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged there or use DependencyProperties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you set
ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="False"?

This way, the validation maybe only triggered by changes after initializing the grid.
[see MSDN for detailed explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule.validatesontargetupdated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If I understand you correctly, you expect also initial errors to be validated, so you should set this property True.